# Segoe UI font in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am using custom Segoe UI font in my CSS file. This font renders properly in Chrome but in IE and Firefox it is showing the default font in some places.

Here is the CSS code

```
body {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0;
    background-color:#eee;
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size::11px;
    color:#333;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
 @font-face {
     font-family:"Segoe UI";
 src: url(images/font/SEGOEUI.eot) format("truetype") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
 src: url(images/font/SEGOEUI.ttf) /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

Comment: will it be  font-size::11px; or  font-size:11px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead of your code:

```
 body {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0;
    background-color:#eee;
    font-family:'Segoe UI' !important;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  src: url('fonts/SEGOEUI.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/SEGOEUI.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('fonts/SEGOEUI.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/SEGOEUI.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('fonts/SEGOEUI.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  }
```

Comment: Still the same. It rendres in few parts of the page but not the full page

Comment: I have edited the code, please use it and check now, also be confirm that you have assigned everything to this font.

Comment: No luck :( I have given font-family only for body, nowhere in the css file

Comment: Ok. Check one more thing. The path I have used, is it right ? I mean     fonts/SEGOEUI.

Comment: But it works when I wrap it with another font-face. Is this valid to use? `@font-face { @font-face {Code here} }`